# Color of icon when changing color of button

Tags: apache-flex, button, colors, icons, flex4.5

I have a button with an icon. I want to have the button in gray so I change the `chromeColor` but when I do that, the icon became darker.

[image: left: button unchange - right:button with other color]

On the left the button without changing the color, on the right, the gray button with and darker icon.
How can I have a gray button without changing the icon color
?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by modifying the skin class and adding  "iconDisplay" to the exclusion array. At the end the line should look like this:

```
static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay","iconDisplay"];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What SDK are you using? If you are in the 4.* range, then I think you should look at applying a custom skin on the button.

Comment: There is the flex4.5 tag so... I'm using Flex 4.5

Comment: Yeah...I didn't see that. Well if so than I suggest working with a custom skin.

Answer (score 0):

As said, it can be done through a custom skin. To create a custom skin with flash builder:

1. Create a new package "skins" inside "src".
2. Right click on skins and click on "New > MXML Skin".
3. Give it a name, for instance "CustomButtonSkin".
4. Pick the host component "spark.components.Button".
5. Create as copy of "spark.skins.spark.ButtonSkin".
6. Add "iconDisplay" to the "exclusions:Array".

   ```
   static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay", "iconDisplay"];
   ```
7. Apply the new custom skin to your buttons.

   ```
   <s:Button id="MyCustomButton" skinClass="skins.CustomButtonSkin" icon="@Embed(source='...')" />
   ```