# Creating Flex button skin with BitmapImage icons

Tags: apache-flex, button, icons, flash-builder, skin

I have been following a good tutorial about creating a Button skin that allows you to add different images:

http://brianackermann.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/flex-4-reusable-icon-button-skins/#expandSource

After a couple of minor changes it worked well, but when I use the same class, skin & images in another project the images always look blended or transparent. I have tried adjusting image blendmode settings and alpha in the skin, app and stylesheet.

The 2 green images should match, as should the white ones. The buttons are the blue squares:

[**https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8YZs.jpg**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8YZs.jpg)

The background XX's are to show where the images should be opaque

(Edit, separating this part from post to avoid confusion after it was solved in comments):
There was an error because the Label in my skin did not have an **id=“LabelDisplay”**. The button in the downloaded tutorial project did not need this. Once I added the **id=“LabelDisplay”** this part was solved.

Comment: 1./ Though I can see you try to explain your issue as well as you can, it's still to vague to be able to make any suggestions (for me anyway).  2./ Since Flex 4.5 the Button class has an `icon` style built-in, so that makes that tutorial kind of obsolete.

Comment: Sorry I could not be more specific, but I have no idea what could cause this. Masking? Blending? Is it inherited? Flex version differences? Options? Etc! I found Flex's icon handling minimal, eg, you cannot control the icon's size. The tutorial shows you how to create & pass your own arguments, eg, you could add a Glow filter to the image in the skin and create arguments for the Glow colour & strength to control from your app:

Comment: If you need that amount of control, I tend to create custom skins rather than generic ones (that's just my approach of course). As for your real question, here are some guesses: 1./ regarding `labelDisplay`: it is not a required skinPart in Flex 4.5 and up, but it could be that it was required in earlier versions (which I don't have lying around anymore to verify); this would explain any differences there. 2./ regarding the colors: it seems like some kind of `BlendMode` is applied, but perhaps a screenshot would say more than your description.

Comment: Thanks, that explains the LabelDisplay. I tried adjusting BlendMode on the images and fill Rect in the button skin. I tried to add screenshots, but got this message: "We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images..."

Comment: Solved part of the problem, the blue button colour was in css global chrome-color. I think it was from Spark theme.

Comment: I bumped your reputation a bit, but I don't know whether it'll be sufficient to upload images. In any case you can always upload an image to a service like 'imgur' and just paste the link.

Comment: Thanks, RIAstar, I have edited and added links. Had not seen imgur before, great & easy way to share images. Some rep coming your way too!

Comment: Right now I can think of only 2 reasonable explanations for that: either some graphic element is laying over the icon (with some transparency or blendmode), or the button itself is transparent and becomes darker because of the DropShadowFilter behind it. Either way, try removing some graphic elements from your skin and see what happens.

Comment: All the elements are required, but I emptied their contents and it didn't help. Removed the skin's scripting and soon found that changing useChromeColor to false in skin's initializationComplete() and setting button fill colours in the skin itself made the image look correct (highlightStroke gave the button a white border so I removed that). It seems that initializationComplete overrides initializationComplete in UIComponent class and useChromeColor is in SparkSkin class. My AS3 is minimal, but it seems the blending/alpha was inherited from one of those classes. Thanks again, RIAstar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IconButton skin was an array constant **exclusions**. Simply adding the id of the BitmapImage to this array caused the BitmapImage to be excluded from colorization by SparkSkin class:

```
static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay","icon"];
```

It displays correctly now.

Comment: Thanks. For those having trouble with this, I've posted more instructions of how to do it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25772205/2573896